# ¿Como insertar dato a un input sin ID desde visual basic?

Tags: html, vb.net

tengo este problema, actualmente el codigo corre bien siempre y cuando el elemento html tenga un ID, la cosa es que a la caja de texto que quiero meter el dato no tiene ID, solo tiene class.

**Codigo que funciona si solamente tiene id:**

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", User_abaol.Text)
```

**Elemento donde quiero insetar dato.**

```
< input class="login" value="texto a insetar"/ >
```

Como puedo insetarlo si la caja de texto html no tiene ID.

Comment: El metodo [getElementsByTagName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx) retorna un listado del tipo HtmlElementCollection. Puedes invocar el metodo con el tag name "input" y buscar el elemento en esa colección.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelvelo así:

```html
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementByClassName("login").SetAttribute("value", User_abaol.Text);
```

También Puedes Consultar en la w3Schools que haya te lo explican un poco...